# JS SDK in pure native application (No server support)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can i use the facebook JS sdk for client only native applications? I am trying to integrate a c++ application to the graph api and would like to know the best way to handle login flows. I do not have a server at my end, although my application uses a webkit. Alternatively, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/ mentions that i could invoke a login dialog with an end-point. Is there a way to make it as a one-time login? (More like automatically checking "Keep me logged in" option).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the JS file to include was missing 'http' and it worked up to a point. Although, it might not be possible to use JS for client only applications. The facbook configuration requires a valid app domain which is not present in my case.